# Is it possible to apply different not embedded fonts for different sets of characters?

Tags: apache-flex, localization, fonts, flex4

I need to apply different system fonts like SimSun and Calibri for different sets of characters, for example, A,B,C... and 承, 認 ...
I have that problem because hieroglyphs are unreadable in Calibri, but english letters look ugly in SimSun. And I want my application to look pretty in both languages. So does anyone know how I can figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to dynamically load different embedded fonts with CSS styles based on the current locale (which would determine which character sets are needed).

First create the embedded fonts.

English.css

```
@font-face {
        fontFamily: Calibri;
        fontStyle: normal;
        fontWeight: normal;
        ...
}

Application
{
        font-family: Calibri;
}
```

Other.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family:SimSun;
    ... 
}

Application {
    font-family: SimSun
}
```

Then based on your locale, select the file to load. The CSS is declared so that the font is applied to your entire application, so you'll only need to do this in one place, probably on application `preInitialize`.

Application.mxml

```
loadLocaleFont() {
    var cssFileToLoad = getLocaleCssFile();
    var styleEvent:IEventDispatcher = StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(cssFileToLoad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a switch in a custom **FontManagement class**. If a language is not supported by your main font, revert to another font or use the system font (client's default). Use the class as a centralized point where to format your `Label` or `TextField` objects.

Optionally you can try to embed your fonts within a css `class` and  assign the `style` name to your `Label` or `TextField` objects. Both should work.

```
var params:Object = {color:0xffffff , size:12, supported:false , etc...};
var tf:TextField= FontManagement.formatTextField(tf , params );

public class FontManagement
{
    public static function formatTextField( textfield:TextField , params:Object ):TextField
    {
        if( params.supported )
           tf.embedFonts = true;
        else
           tf.embedFonts = false;

        return textfield;
    }
}
```